# How to make cross-platform notifications with a custom sound in Electron?

Tags: javascript, notifications, electron

I'm struggling to find information about properly making notifications with a custom alert sound in Electron. How is it recommended that we do this in both the main and renderer processes?

Here's an example attempt I put in my main process (I know the path is not the issue here) where it plays the default sound anyway:

```
let exNotification = new Notification({
  title: "Example!",
  body: "Here's an example!",
  silent: false,
  sound: path.join(
    app.getAppPath(), "assets/ping.mp3"),
});
exNotification.show();
```

...and even if this *did* work, it would be MacOS only.

There seems to be a variety of packages for this, but there's nothing definitive I can find that simply says what the "right" way is for working cross-platform.

There's a lot of hacky-feeling suggestions like "make the notification silent and use a different package to play a sound at the same time," or "use this 3rd party notification package that hasn't been updated in a couple years," and I am worried about the long-term viability of those options.

Any advice? What is the "proper" way of doing cross-platform notifications with custom sounds like the big Electron apps do, like Slack or Discord? Would something like Tauri or some other web-app wrapper work better for this that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

I think that is better if you set the notification as silent and fire a sound from the app.

```js
const sound = require("sound-play");

const exNotification = new Notification({
  title: "Example!",
  body: "Here's an example!",
  silent: true
});

exNotification.show();
sound.play("./{your_path}/assets/ping.mp3");
```

Also I suggest this [module](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/electron-notification-state), so you will reproduce the sound only if notifications are allowed for your app.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful for the main process, but not the renderer!